# CSS transitions flickering during multiple changes

Tags: css

In short, I have a button with a darker bottom border, and, on hover, I want the button to move down a little and shrink the border (to give the effect of pressing it).

However, it jitters slightly as it animates, completely killing the feel of the button "pressing".

Here's a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrt2mkns/)** demonstrating the issue, along with the CSS in question:

```
.btn {
  color: grey;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) solid;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 250ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  top: 2px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

*I'm not using the prefixes like `-webkit` here for the sake of simplicity.*

The main issue is the bottom border. The button slides down fine, but the border appears to be doing something different (and isn't smooth).

Any ideas here?

Comment: You are encouraged to use `opacity`, and `transform` properties for best performance.

Comment: I see no jitter in Safari, but I see it in FireFox, Opera and Google Chrome. What is happening is that the button (top) goes down 1px. then the border width goes down one pixel, then the button goes down another pixel and then the border again. I would try a different approach. Maybe add box shadow and only make a transition on the box shadow. You could also place two buttons on top of each other with position and z-index and then only move the button down with the highest z-index. This way, the transition also handles only one transition.

Comment: You can try this with box-shadow (https://jsfiddle.net/vishal_vash/2w3v8rcc/)

Comment: This solution may seem a bit over-complicated, but works a lot smoother: https://jsfiddle.net/qjfstq1c/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the `top` transition with `transform: translateY(2px)`, also replace the bottom border with a `::before` pseudo element and animate it's `scale` property:

https://jsfiddle.net/qjfstq1c/1/

```
.btn, .btn:before {
   transition: all 250ms;
   transform-origin: top center;
 }
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: grey;
  background: lightgrey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #bebebe;
}
.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
.btn:hover:before {
  transform: scaleY(.5);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was thinking of doing. While it over-complicates things a little, it does have the desired effect.